# Session keyword arguments are not support during eager execution error in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I execute a code snippet bellow I get error:

> Session keyword arguments are not support during eager execution. You passed: {'metricks': ['accuracy']}.

```py
model.compile(optimizer ='adam',
             loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             metricks=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train,
                   y_train_one_hot,
                   validation_data=(X_test, y_test_one_hot),
                   epochs=3)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

change `metrics` with `metricks`. you have spelling issue.

Comment: I did it but get different thing. ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (10,)

Comment: y_train_one = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test_one = to_categorical(y_test)
print(y_train_one_hot[0])
#create model
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

Comment: you need to send your whole code. obviousely you have a dimensionality problem. and please use the right format to send your problem so others can help you easier.